# My JavaScript Code Keeps Getting an Undefined Message

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, undefined

Having to do a new class and JS confuses me to this day.

My code is this but I keep getting an error...

```
/*Instructions
 - Greet your friend by printing a message to the console.
*/

*

var myFriend = "Sergia";

function greetings() {
  console.log(`Greetings ${myFriend}.`);
}

//leave this line unchanged to console log the results

console.log('results: ', greetings());

//don't change this line

if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = greetings;
}*
```

Help me please!

Comment: _"Inside the greetings function, return the string"_ - you missed this part. Replace the `console.log` statement inside the `greetings` function with the following statement: `return \`Greetings ${myFriend}.\``

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: In greetings() function you are console logging not returning try returning it rather logging and then u can console log the function

Answer (score 2):

Your `greetings` function doesn't return anything to be logged, which is why it's printing `undefined` -- that's the default return value of a function that doesn't explicitly return anything. What you should instead do is return a value, which is then logged by the `console.log` that calls `greetings()`. You shouldn't be calling `console.log` in your function. Like this:

```js
/*Instructions
 - Greet your friend by printing a message to the console.
*/

var myFriend = "Sergia";

function greetings() {
  return `Greetings ${myFriend}.`;
}

//leave this line unchanged to console log the results

console.log('results: ', greetings());

//don't change this line

if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = greetings;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myFriend = "Sergia";
function greetings() {
    console.log(`Greetings ${myFriend}.`);
  }
  greetings();
```

`u should not use console.log for greetings() function....It has console.log already inside the function....you should only call it`
**OR**
*you can try:*

```
var myFriend = "Sergia";
function greetings() {
    return `Greetings ${myFriend} `
  }
  console.log(greetings());
```

Comment: this works **But this is not what he wanted**. Read the question again properly

Answer (score 0):

in the `greetings` function, you have `` console.log(`Greetings ${myFriend}.`) ``

```
function greetings() {
  console.log(`Greetings ${myFriend}.`);
}
```

so if you console.log the function like `console.log('results: ', greetings());`, it will not return anything

so you can use `return` instead in the function like

```
function greetings() {
  return `Greetings ${myFriend}.`;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! I appreciate you!

Comment: @undefinedmyself glad i could help, consider accepting the answer by clicking the tick :D